# jQuery Mobile Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to have some swipe functionality on an image gallery on the mobile version of a site I'm building, so as I've been using jQuery, I thought I'd use the jQuery Mobile `swipeleft` and `swiperight`events.  This all works fine, but I notice that when the page loads I get a the word loading appear on the page.

Is this the loading widget? And if so how can I set it so that it doesn't show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn it of with a:

```
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```

It is also good to know that this block must be initialized before jQuery Mobile is initialized inside a HEAD, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>          
    <script>
        $( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
            $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
            $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
            $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
            $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
        });     
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Find more about this functionality [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/loader.html).

Comment: Thanks @Gajotres for your answer and pointer about initializing the block before initializing jQuery Mobile in the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on("swiperight", "body", function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

OR

```
$("body").on( "swipeleft swiperight", function( event ) {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

however you do it, the important piece is

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```